# How to make a non-blocking sleep in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sleep

How to make a non-blocking sleep in javascript/jquery?

Comment: You mean like a [timeout?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Comment: How do you make a blocking sleep in javascript?

Comment: @aF - you're going to need more detail about what you want before you can get a useful response. Are you looking for anything other than `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @Dykam, `var halt=+new Date+3000;while(1){if(new Date>halt)break;}console.log('done after blocking for 3 seconds')`

Comment: Yeah, blocking sleep can be done. For example function `pausecomp(millis) 
{
var date = new Date();
var curDate = null;

do { curDate = new Date(); } 
while(curDate-date < millis);
}` As for non-blocking obviously `setTimeout()`

Comment: @davin, those are spin loops. Those aren't sleeps, just waits. Sleeps don't keep the CPU busy. The opposite really.

Comment: There is no non-blocking sleep in javascript.  There are spin loops (eeck, horrible) and there are timeouts.  Those are the two options.

Comment: what I wanted is exactly what Lucas answered!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the risk of stealing the answer from your commentors, use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).  For example:

```
var aWhile = 5000; // 5 seconds
var doSomethingAfterAWhile = function() {
  // do something
}
setTimeout( doSomethingAfterAWhile, aWhile );
```

Answer (score 2):

since ECMAScript 2017 you can benefit from [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

https://jsfiddle.net/2tavp61e/

```js
function delay (miliseconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, miliseconds);
    });
}

(async function () {
    console.log('A');
    await delay(2000);
    console.log('B');
})();

console.log('C');
```

"A" appears in the console first, "C" comes immediately after - which is proof that delay is non-blocking, and finally after two seconds there comes "B".

Answer (score 0):

**Inside Node, without using  `new Promise()` explicity**

```
      const util = require("util");
      const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout);
      await sleep(5000); // waiting 5 seconds
      // now send response
      await res.status(401).send("incorrect username or password");
      return;
```